# Why is it that Windows Java cannot bind to a port that has already been bound?

Tags: java, windows, sockets, bind

We have the need to bind to the same local port when responding to requests.
Below is a sample of Java code. On Linux we can bind to the same port twice,
but on Windows we get error on second bind.  The error is BindException: Address already in use. A similar program written in C allows us to bind twice.
What is preventing Java on Windows from doing this?  Is there a registry setting to allow the bind?

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

public class SocketTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Socket s1 = new Socket();
        s1.setReuseAddress(true);
        SocketAddress saremote = new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80);
        SocketAddress salocal = new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.98", 9990);
        s1.bind(salocal);
        s1.connect(saremote);

        Socket s2 = new Socket();
        s2.setReuseAddress(true);
        SocketAddress saremote2 = new InetSocketAddress("yahoo.com", 80);
        SocketAddress salocal2 = new InetSocketAddress("10.1.1.98", 9990);
        s2.bind(salocal2);
        s2.connect(saremote2); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Socket stream connections are TCP and you can only bind to a port once with TCP, then the connection has to be closed before you can rebind to the same port

Comment: How is the C program similar? I have the feeling that the parts where it's different are relevant here.

Comment: You have *what* need? If this is a so-called security feature implemented by the net admin at the firewall, have it removed. The security benefit is zero, and it makes applications infeasible.

Comment: Our JAVA FTP Server app needs to bind to the same local port when responding to FTP PORT requests(i.e. Control Port-1).  User's firewall is configured to only allow FTP out from port 20.  Unique address is made up of remote address and port and local address and port.  If remote addresses are the different then local port can be the same.

Answer (score 3):

Use -Dsun.net.useExclusiveBind=false

There has been a change in the Networking API Implementation on Windows platforms.
The implementation of the networking APIs has been changed on Windows to use the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE socket option by default. This change is necessary to address anomalies that arise when using both IPv4 and IPv6 applications that require to bind to the same port.

This change may cause issues for applications that rely on the ability to have multiple processes bound to the same address and port. When such issues occur, use the sun.net.useExclusiveBind system property as a temporary workaround to restore legacy behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible on both Linux and Windows. You probably have another application (maybe a previous version of your application, which did not terminate) running and using the same port.

Comment: The first bind always succeeds, so the port is available.  The second bind fails.